Vertical alignment in twocolumn grid
I am setting an article using a class file provided by the journal (openjournal.cls), which defines the following thebibliography environment.
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{
 \if@chicago \onecolumngrid \else \twocolumngrid \fi
 \par
 \raggedright
 \vspace{10pt plus 3pt}
 \if@chicago
    \noindent \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\footnotesize REFERENCES}
 \else
    \centerline{\normalsize REFERENCES}
 \fi
 \par
 \if@chicago
    \vspace*{4pt plus 3pt}
    \set@column@hsize{2}
    \twocolumngrid
 \fi
 \list{}%
   {
     \parindent=0pt \parskip=0pt \parsep=0pt % AV
     \bibindent=0pt                          %
     \def\baselinestretch{1.0}
     \footnotesize \baselineskip=\bibbaselineskip \interlinepenalty \@M  % AV
     \frenchspacing    % AV - to get right spacing after ``et al.'' 
     \hyphenpenalty=10000
     \itemindent=-1.0em                      %
     \itemsep=0pt                            %
     \listparindent=0pt                      %
     \settowidth\labelwidth{0pt} %
     \labelsep=0pt                           %
     \leftmargin=1.0em
     \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
%%%      \usecounter{enumiv}%
      \let\p@enumiv\@empty
      \renewcommand\theenumiv{\relax}}%
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.\@m}
  {\def\@noitemerr
    {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \endlist
    \onecolumngrid % to balance references
    \if@two@col \twocolumngrid \fi
  }

which in turn uses twocolumngrid from revtex4.cls.
This produces output like that in the picture below, which is not vertically balanced (14 lines on the left vs 11 on the right column of the bibliography). I wonder how this can be typeset so that it is vertically balanced (I can edit openjournal.cls, but am not a TeX expert and won't import further packages).


Just curious: Is there a requirement to balance the column heights, or is this (mainly) an aesthetic concern of yours? Have you contacted the journal's editorial office about your concern and asked them for their point of view? BTW, the crucial directives would appear to be \onecolumngrid % to balance references, followed immediately by \if@two@col \twocolumngrid \fi, in the closing part of the redefined thebibliography environment. However, we don't know how \onecolumngrid and \twocolumngrid are defined, so it's not easy to determine what, if anything, can be done.

@Mico The twocolumngrid is defined in revtex4.cls

Thanks for this additional piece of information. I looked up the definitions of \onecolumngrid and \twocolumngrid and of several associated auxilliary macros; unfortunately, I was unable to figure out how they're supposed to perform the column balancing work. Sorry.

@Mico Thanks for you effort. It's a pity that you couldn't get to the bottom of the issue. Was this because the code is too complex? or because you didn't have enough time?

A bit of both. The \onecolumngrid macro relies on several auxilliary macros, and I wasn't able to figure out which one of these auxilliary macros is actually supposed to do the column-rebalanciing work. Plus, I must confess to not feeling a huge amount of enthusiasm for designing a solution that has a net value that's either zero or negative. I still don't understand why you would care about the column balancing matter. AFAICT, it's an issue that is for the journal to handle, not for you. Your job is to write good papers...

@Mico My interest is because I am one of the editors of a journal that uses openjournal.cls, which in turn uses revtex-4.cls ...

Thanks. Most queries on this site come from users rather than maintainers or designers of journal templates. May I suggest that you post a new query, to mention the macros \onecolumngrid and \twocolumngrid, plus associated auxilliary macros such as \do@columngrid and \csname open@column@#1\endcsname, and to ask which one of these macros might be involved in the column rebalancing business? Hopefully, somebody with some experience will see your posting and come up with an answer. BTW, I was not one of the persons who voted to close this posting as being "in need of detail or clarity".
